# Very slow rendering of stylesheets in development

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, puma

Whenever I change any css file, it takes up to 20 seconds to load a view, whereas if I change just change html, it only takes a few seconds.  I am using rails 4.2.2, with a puma server and have `config.assets.debug = false` in my `development.rb` file. Looking at the log, most of the time spent here:

```
  Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (15.0ms)
source=rack-timeout id=300494b919b8d4bc3128df494ef27e47 timeout=30000ms service=2005ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=300494b919b8d4bc3128df494ef27e47 timeout=30000ms service=3005ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=300494b919b8d4bc3128df494ef27e47 timeout=30000ms service=4003ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=300494b919b8d4bc3128df494ef27e47 timeout=30000ms service=5003ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=300494b919b8d4bc3128df494ef27e47 timeout=30000ms service=6004ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=300494b919b8d4bc3128df494ef27e47 timeout=30000ms service=7005ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=300494b919b8d4bc3128df494ef27e47 timeout=30000ms service=8002ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=300494b919b8d4bc3128df494ef27e47 timeout=30000ms service=9005ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=300494b919b8d4bc3128df494ef27e47 timeout=30000ms service=10005ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=300494b919b8d4bc3128df494ef27e47 timeout=30000ms service=11001ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=300494b919b8d4bc3128df494ef27e47 timeout=30000ms service=12003ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=300494b919b8d4bc3128df494ef27e47 timeout=30000ms service=13005ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=300494b919b8d4bc3128df494ef27e47 timeout=30000ms service=14005ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=300494b919b8d4bc3128df494ef27e47 timeout=30000ms service=15003ms state=active
Completed 200 OK in 15542ms (Views: 15535.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

My applications.css.scss is as follows:

```
/*
*= require_self
*/
$Tempo-green: #6dbd63;
$site_width: 992px;
$grid-float-breakpoint: 992px;
$btn-default-bg: $Tempo-green;
$btn-default-color: #fff;
$btn-primary-bg: #6dbd63;
$field_bg: lighten($btn-default-bg, 30%);
$Mentor-green: #006400;
$Mentor-grey: #E6E6E6;
$Mentor-light-green: #AAE9AA;
@mixin standard-text{
    color:  #636363;
    font-family: 'Georgia, Helvetica', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;  
    }
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import 'bootstrap_and_overrides';
@import "compass";
@import "compass/css3";
@import "flexslider.css";
@import "admin.css.scss";
@import "accounts.css.scss";
@import "central.css.scss";
@import "common.css.scss";
@import "custom.css.scss";
@import "articles.css.scss";
@import "graph.css.scss";
@import "handicaps.css.scss";
@import "pages.css.scss";
@import "jquery.countdown.css";
@import "setups.css.scss";
@import "shared.css.scss";
@import "landings.css.scss";
@import "linkages.css.scss";
@import "professionals.css.scss";
@import "pro_users.css.scss";
@import "subscribers.css.scss";
@import "reviews.css.scss";
@import "mental_games.css.scss";
@import "students.css.scss";
@import "morris.css";
@import "users.css.scss";
@import "print.css.scss"
```

/* rest of file omitted */

My _layout.html.erb is

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 8]><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/ie' %><![endif]-->
```

What is causing this?

Comment: can u show _stylesheets.html.erb?

Comment: I have added the contents of _stylesheets.html.erb to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [Matt Brictson post](https://mattbrictson.com/lightning-fast-sass-reloading-in-rails) gives a good approach to improving your page reload time, particularly if you are using sass.  What I ended up doing is as follows:

I first eliminated the need for using `compass`, by replacing all my compass calls with the [autoprefixer gem](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer). This had a remarkable effect, reducing my load time to about 8 seconds.

Brictson suggests replacing most `@import` commands with the old school sprockets `//= require` commands, but would require quite a bit of rewiring.
Instead I tried the [sassc-rails gem](https://github.com/sass/sassc-rails) which is meant to reduce sass compilation times by a factor of four. However, I hit an [issue with sassc-rails](https://github.com/sass/sassc-rails/issues/55).  When this problem is fixed, I will probably use this gem.

Next I started using `guard` and `livereload`, as described by Brictson.  This means that now changes to my html load in about 4 seconds and changes to sass are often less than one second.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4 uses the asset pipeline.
Every file name of an asset (stylsheet, js (or coffee) script, picture) is modified by an hash of the content, even in development.
This hash has to be recalculated whenever you change any asset.

20 seconds seem to be quite long but depending on your assets might be in a normal range.

Comment: You are basically right so I have upvoted your answer. However, I am finding there are a number of simple changes that can considerably reduce the time. I am now down to 8 seconds and am working on some further suggestions. When I am finished I will post an answer.

Comment: Great, I'm looking forward to see your results. Hopefully it will make a better answer ;-)